# Access 2007 - Forms created on the fly

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Hopefully I can find some words of advice from somebody.

Is it possible to create forms 'on-the fly' so to speak in MS-Access 2007

I have a structure of tables:

tblCustomer
tblQuestAns

A customer may answer the questionnaire answers many times as they relate to all products.

I propose to hopefully have an initial input form that will ask how many products of which there could be more than 1
eg: TV, Video (say the user selects 2)

On entering that data the next form should hopefully update itself to include the list of questions eg

### TV

Q1, Q2 Q3

-

### Video (1)

Q1, Q2 Q3

-

### Video (2)

Q1, Q2 Q3

Is that possible? Any point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks
Noel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably want to do a subform with a variable number of records.

Comment: thanks for your answers folks, need to spend some time figuring this out

Answer (score 1):

Rather than create a form on the fly, how about the following?

Create a form which has a continous subform to display questions for a customer.

After the customer answers how many products on the initial input form, you create blank records in the answers table.

Then open the questions form which loads the customers blank records for them to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear on how the questions are being associated with the product, or how the user is selecting the products they are inputting information on, but one possibility is to populate an array and then pull up a form for each product that was selected with the associated questions.

To properly loop through the array you would use a function to wait for the form to close before moving on to the next index.  Here's a function that I use:

```
Sub WaitForFormClose(strFormName As String)
    While SysCmd(acSysCmdGetObjectState, acForm, strFormName) = acObjStateOpen
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```